# Blazor - Resolve WASM inital load status code 429 when downloading DLL's

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I have a .NET7 Blazor Web Assembly, Azure Web App deployed and I have encountered an issue on the inital load to do with the DLL's required by WASM.

[image: Console Errors]

These console errors show the SHA integrity check failing for the DLL and therefore throwing the "failed to fetch" error when trying to cache the DLL.

Upon further inspection I noticed that in the network tab I found the same DLL throwing the 429 when initially trying to download.

[image: Network Error]

This shows the 429 error which fails to download the DLL, the failed SHA check makes sense.

When the page first loads there are around 192* requests

[image: Network Requests]

I have searched the wider Blazor Community and I have stuggled to find a solution to this problem, once the DLL's are cached (upon refresh) it will often work, however frequently fails on the first time.

Why is this error thrown when trying to download the necessary DLL's for the application to run? 
Where is the limit set for the amount of DLL's that it is allowed to download?

Any suggestions would be wonderful,
Thanks

*edit: Sorry for picture links. I don't have enough rep to show them. 
*edit2: Thanks for the rep :)

[blazor](/questions/tagged/blazor) [webassembly](/questions/tagged/webassembly) [wasm](/questions/tagged/wasm)

Comment: Well the answer is not really... However I did find a "work-around".

I opted to lazy load my project so that the calls are only made when they are needed and this seemed to help a lot. This is not a long term solutiion but it has made things a lot more consistent.

Comment: From what I read online there are a couple of things that could cause this.

1 - The configuration of the Front Door profile
2 - The configuration of the firewall settings on the network

I know this isn't a solid solution and I appologise but if I come across one I will pop it on this post.

best of luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I increased my service plan and added more webapp instance using the scale up feature. I don't have user complaining about this issue anymore, but absolutely none of the metrics showed that we were at the service plan limits. Even our cloud expert didn't understand this.
I thought about lazy loading too. But I need to review my architecture before. 
Best of luck for you too ;)